# Add a word to the first // wp_get_attachment_url // as the subdomain name

Tags: attachments

We use this code to display the link ...

```
$mp3Link = wp_get_attachment_url($mp3_file_id);
<a class="w3-black" href="'.$mp3Link.'" rel="nofollow" >mp3</a>
```

It looks like this now :

https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Amir.mp3

I want it to be like this :

https://sub.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Amir.mp3

I mean, I just want to do this by editing the above code

Comment: Do you mean that the second URL works and you just want a way to edit the first string so that is matches? - You could do something like $string = str_replace( 'domain.com', 'sub.domain.com', $string);

Comment: Or check out this filter - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_url/

Comment: I do not know how to please embed in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mp3Link = wp_get_attachment_url($mp3_file_id);
$mp3Link = str_replace( 'example.com', 'sub.example.com', $mp3Link ); 
<a class="w3-black" href="'.$mp3Link.'" rel="nofollow" >mp3</a>
```

replace `example.com` with your actual domain - it's not the most elegant solution, but might work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I love you buddy